# Add Spacebar as a modifier key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I want to configure my shortcuts to switch between multiple desktops. Currently, I am using <kbd>Control</kbd> as the modifier key, but that's a bit too difficult for me to reach. I want to use the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> as a modifier key. So I can assign shortcuts like:

1. <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>: Desktop 1 (Holds Google Chrome)
2. <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>: Desktop 2 (Holds IntelliJ)
3. <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: Desktop 3 (Holds Terminal)
4. <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>: Desktop 4 (Holds Postman)

The system won't let me use <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> as a modifier key. If I use <kbd>Command</kbd> (which is a bit easier for me to reach), then it collides with my copy and paste shortcuts.

I would prefer a native solution but I am ready to use an app as well.

Comment: Hey Prashant! There are shortcuts like `^1` to switch to Desktop 1 and so on. Isn't that helpful? You can use `cmd` in them. Safari can cause conflicts since `cmd+x` gives x number tab.

Comment: It's too hard for me to reach. Can't I use the space as one of the modifier keys?

Comment: The problem arises when you're in say, a document and want to press `space + c`. So wouldn't the system try to insert spaces in the document while you hold the `space` key and reach out for c? You said that `cmd` is easier, so I suggested `cmd+1` etc.

Comment: Why would I ever press space + c in a document? The thing is, I have mapped the keys according to the application: c for Chrome, t for the terminal etc. If I remap now, I'll have to build up the muscle memory again.

Comment: To go to chrome. It was an example. You might want to press I T or P also depending on your need. The point is still that `space`  *has* other function which is to insert spaces in editable conditions.

Comment: Hey thanks got it. I remapped the copy and paste shortcuts, so cmd works perfectly now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are native shortcuts which let you go to specific Desktop by <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> etc.

But according to your needs to remove your conflicts with Copy/Paste shortcut, edit the keys by going to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts. Then you can add/edit Shortcuts to use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> etc for going to specific applications.